# Finitely generated flat modules over a commutative, local, Noetherian ring are free

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

> I'm trying to prove that finitely generated flat modules over a commutative, local, Noetherian ring are free.

I think I've got really close to a proof, but I'm stuck at the last step that finishes the proof.

So, suppose that $M$ is a finitely generated flat $R$-module, and $(R,m,k)$ is a commutative, local ring which is Noetherian. $M/mM$ is a $k$-vector space and so is $k \otimes M$ and we know that they're isomorphic.
Therefore, $\dim(M/mM)=\dim(k \otimes M)$ as $k$-vector spaces. A theorem states that $\dim(M/mM)$ is equal to the number elements of a minimal generating set which is a well-defined finite number. Let's say it's equal to $\dim(M/mM)=n$.

I know every $R$-module is the image of a homomorphism $F \to M$ where $F$ is free (just think of the elements of $M$ as a basis for $F$). Therefore, we get a short exact sequence:
$$ 0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow F \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$$
where $L=\ker(F\rightarrow M)$.
Tensoring with $k$ we get:

$$ \cdots \rightarrow {\rm Tor}_1^R(k,M)\rightarrow k\otimes L \rightarrow k \otimes F \rightarrow k\otimes M \rightarrow 0$$
But since $M$ is flat, we get the short exact sequence:

$$ 0\rightarrow k\otimes L \rightarrow k \otimes F \rightarrow k\otimes M \rightarrow 0$$

OK. Now here I think I need to compare the dimensions. If I can prove that $k \otimes L = 0$, then Nakayama's lemma gives $L=0$ and that proves $M \cong F$ and I'm done. But I have no idea how to show that $\dim(k\otimes F) = \dim(k \otimes M)$.

Comment: In fact, one only needs to show that $F=\oplus_{i=1}^n R$ ($n$ copies of $R$). Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you use Nakayama to show that you can choose $F$ to be of this form?

Comment: @Mohan: Do you mean Nakayama's lemma?

Comment: When you choose a minimal system of generators for $M$ then they form a basis in $k\otimes M$.

Comment: @user26857: Yes because if $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ generates $M$, $\{ 1\otimes x_1, \cdots, 1\otimes x_n \}$ generates $k \otimes M$. My question is why $F$ is exactly $n$ copies of $R$? (Or is it?) where $n$ is the number of elements of a minimal generating set for $M$. I think Mohan suggested that I should Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: Now just take $F$ a free module of rank $n$ and send its basis to the minimal generating set of $M$. What about $\dim_kk\otimes F$? Isn't this equal to the rank of $F$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A finitely generated module over a noetherian ring is finitely presented, and finitely presented flat implies projective. Now use projective finitely generated implies free over local rings (this is a straightforward application of Nakayama).

Comment: I don't know what a finitely presented module is. It isn't in the topics covered in my course. Can we do it without that?

Comment: @H.Z. A module $M$ is finitely generated if there is an exact sequence $F_0\to M\to 0$ where $F_0$ is free and finitely generated. A module is finitely presented if there is an exact sequence $F_1\to F_0\to M\to 0$ where both $F_1,F_0$ are free and finitely generated.

Comment: I see. Thanks. But why do they define finitely-presented modules? Is it any useful? Does it have to do with free resolutions?

Comment: @H.Z. Well, I gave you one example: projective always implies flat, and finitely presented flat always implies projective. Finitely generated modules are in general more manageable than arbitrary modules.

Answer (score 2):

In your solution, one can choose $F$ to be minimal, i.e. choose a minimal generating set of $M$ and projected by basis elements of $F$ respectively. Then by NAK, $M\otimes k=F\otimes k$ as $k$-vector space.