# Noetherian property is redundant?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I believe everyone knows "in a local Noetherian local commutative ring, a f.g. module is free if and only if it is flat".

The proof is in the question [flat f.g. modules over a commutative, local, Noetherian ring are free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812584/flat-f-g-modules-over-a-commutative-local-noetherian-ring-are-free) . We only need to notice that $k \otimes F$ anf $k\otimes M$ are vectors space of the same finite dimension.

Anyway, I do not see where the Noetherian property is used. NAK lemma does not require it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The proof cited argues that a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring is finitely presented. This is not true in general if the ring is not Noetherian. However, I believe that the equivalence “free $⇔$ flat” of finitely generated modules nevertheless holds for arbitrary local rings. (I don’t have a source, though.)

Comment: I understand your point. But dont look at the answer in the link, look at the proof in the question. It is the same proof in R. Ash's commutative algebra. And I believe it does not require Noetherian priperty

Comment: In this proof: To apply Nakayama to $L$ you need $L$ to be finitely generated. Why would that be the case?

Comment: Thank you. That is what I look over. I only focused on the fact that M is f.g.